Keep Laptop Running with Lid Closed (Ubuntu 24.04)
As the title suggests, I'd like to keep my laptop running while the lid is closed. I know that I can do this on the terminal by modifying the logind configure file. However, is there a way to do this on the GUI? In previous versions of Ubuntu this could be done quite easily with Gnome Tweaks app. Now, however, this feature seems to have been removed.
Is there any way to accomplish this from the GUI or do I really just have to go into the terminal?

If you connect an external monitor to your laptop you can close the lid and it will continue to run!

@user68186 Good to know, thanks.
